# Java applet text fields shortening/not displaying properly

Tags: java, text, applet

I wrote a price calculator for a friend (runescape dungeoneering, but that's not particularly important). He's part of a fairly large group that does this, and one of the other admins is having troubles with it.

I wrote this in Eclipse on Windows 7, Java 6u32 (I believe it was u32). He's running Mac OS X version 10.7.4, with Java 6u33. Whenever he loads the page, the text fields don't display properly. Half of them are shortened with ellipses at the end of the line.

Picture of the problem:

http://puu.sh/KckA

Also, as a side question, I was wondering why the image only shows up after it paints once?

Thanks for all your help, and sorry about the badly named variables! I wasn't able to figure out how to embed code properly into the post, so I realize this is badly space - I just copy/pasted it over and used space to indent the imports :/.

```
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class IHideKeysCalc extends JApplet implements ActionListener {

JRadioButton t = new JRadioButton("Get a chaotic at your current level."), z = new JRadioButton("Get to a certain level.");
JRadioButton t2 = new JRadioButton("Yes."), z2 = new JRadioButton("No.");
JTextField startLevel = new JTextField(), endLevel = new JTextField();
JLabel e = new JLabel("What is your ending level?"), p = new JLabel("What is your starting level?");
JLabel cost = new JLabel("It will cost: 0m");
JLabel chaotics = new JLabel("You will gain: 0 chaotics");
JLabel time = new JLabel("It will take: 0 hours");
JButton calc = new JButton("Calculate!");
JLabel leech = new JLabel("Will you leech c1s from us?");
Color dots = new Color(215, 215, 215);

double[] normalCost = new double[] {0.147408147408147, 0.161616161616162, 0.156052782558807, 0.171352074966533, 0.166624674561182, 0.18543713781809, 0.180714893457874, 0.201060278814058, 0.206251654890812, 0.227434257285004, 0.228290358693966, 0.251523448295564, 0.253108393640709, 0.280820991484583, 0.28508229125052, 0.314016016332662, 0.321855573638658, 0.354987765042637, 0.365389331821599, 0.402884011746955, 0.413233529990681, 0.454829644395684, 0.469244088131267, 0.518269589876325, 0.536842873549166, 0.591842366162221, 0.617068005673544, 0.680805377374742, 0.711865189407446, 0.785616988310019, 0.824813238661612, 0.910191318818822, 0.958469472772604, 1.05785553342935, 1.11731759927444, 1.2328062178794, 1.30540086348993, 1.44105580841818, 1.52112093542576, 1.67893297878229, 1.79759198326453, 1.98403337299274, 2.0576867439263, 2.27198067413181, 2.34861652795415, 2.59287845397998, 2.67171019944355, 2.94948405053316, 2.30627996576819, 2.54621754023429, 2.63839002652197, 2.91292672667821, 3.02782375824338, 3.34294815274889, 2.99278604307127, 3.30403304019601, 3.44280379223394, 3.8011722050782, 3.35899412255012, 3.70845630500912, 3.7979745635451, 4.19312491872546, 4.11809281699623, 4.5465605645372, 4.59525960492191, 5.07347042913889, 5.11281698937835, 5.64488890579082, 5.81225689595036, 6.41724086226737, 6.46511043188491, 7.13790513866952, 7.31926635024289, 8.08104832531242, 8.18451767951496, 9.03633826548025, 9.03072096418207, 9.97065806503748, 11.6582196154413, 12.8716058180737, 13.3368037528554, 14.7248844101516, 15.2703841396691, 16.8597698035761, 17.5341941654067, 19.3591671629348, 20.1405224921476, 22.2368354307871, 23.1540859239001, 25.5640472079718, 26.7502409626548, 29.534621910156, 31.0514204050245, 34.2834446556508, 36.3576095095093, 40.1419477374292, 42.8132373341253, 47.2695988929749, 50.5171187677128, 55.775336875572, 59.0583839135564, 65.2056239687282, 69.5517856204352, 76.791366428954, 80.8126533895158, 89.2243342865382, 94.9773484573605, 104.863428916985, 112.165424237996, 123.840557129701, 130.059514288612, 143.597320738684, 154.344556268421, 170.410147105144, 178.81609217768, 197.428905849894, 209.623017271163, 231.442490011038, 248.40964248305, 2418.96525482347};
double[] normalCost2 = new double[] {0.147408147408147, 0.161616161616162, 0.156052782558807, 0.171352074966533, 0.166624674561182, 0.18543713781809, 0.180714893457874, 0.201060278814058, 0.206251654890812, 0.227434257285004, 0.228290358693966, 0.251523448295564, 0.253108393640709, 0.280820991484583, 0.28508229125052, 0.314016016332662, 0.321855573638658, 0.354987765042637, 0.365389331821599, 0.402884011746955, 0.413233529990681, 0.454829644395684, 0.469244088131267, 0.518269589876325, 0.536842873549166, 0.591842366162221, 0.617068005673544, 0.680805377374742, 0.711865189407446, 0.785616988310019, 0.824813238661612, 0.910191318818822, 0.958469472772604, 1.05785553342935, 1.11731759927444, 1.2328062178794, 1.30540086348993, 1.44105580841818, 1.52112093542576, 1.67893297878229, 1.79759198326453, 1.98403337299274, 2.0576867439263, 2.27198067413181, 2.34861652795415, 2.59287845397998, 2.67171019944355, 2.94948405053316, 2.30627996576819, 2.54621754023429, 2.63839002652197, 2.91292672667821, 3.02782375824338, 3.34294815274889, 2.99278604307127, 3.30403304019601, 3.44280379223394, 3.8011722050782, 3.35899412255012, 3.70845630500912, 3.7979745635451, 4.19312491872546, 4.11809281699623, 4.5465605645372, 4.59525960492191, 5.07347042913889, 5.11281698937835, 5.64488890579082, 5.81225689595036, 6.41724086226737, 6.46511043188491, 7.13790513866952, 7.31926635024289, 8.08104832531242, 8.18451767951496, 9.03633826548025, 9.03072096418207, 9.97065806503748, 9.16677990396157, 10.1208573381611, 10.6767809960961, 11.7880092526936, 12.4151865893764, 13.7073950498449, 14.4486866969796, 15.952517601496, 16.79338694904, 18.5413155024615, 19.5087629499962, 21.5393057908644, 22.749431329251, 25.1173757245215, 26.628575651853, 29.4002428137358, 31.4882868073428, 34.7657940225949, 37.4024999022994, 41.2956664355536, 44.4734040636548, 49.1025449226364, 52.3507084560114, 57.7997632829849, 62.0331408031167, 68.4901128512714, 72.4784892775103, 80.0226781901313, 85.613081327045, 94.52444623818, 101.572293638011, 112.144803254013, 118.272870806207, 130.583813546741, 140.900446941876, 155.566652113006, 163.822838496629, 180.875017252225, 192.680242742557, 212.736157206356, 229.030482784318, 2230.25473010176};
double[] normalTokens = new double[] {8.3, 9.1, 10.2, 11.2, 12.4, 13.8, 15.1, 16.8, 18.5, 20.4, 22.6, 24.9, 27.4, 30.4, 33.5, 36.9, 40.8, 45, 49.7, 54.8, 60.6, 66.7, 73.7, 81.4, 89.8, 99, 109.4, 120.7, 133.2, 147, 162.3, 179.1, 197.7, 218.2, 240.9, 265.8, 293.5, 324, 357.6, 394.7, 435.8, 481, 531, 586.3, 647.1, 714.4, 788.7, 870.7, 961.2, 1061.2, 1171.5, 1293.4, 1427.8, 1576.4, 1740.4, 1921.4, 2121.2, 2342, 2585.6, 2854.6, 3151.6, 3479.5, 3841.6, 4241.3, 4682.6, 5169.9, 5707.9, 6301.9, 6957.6, 7681.8, 8481.2, 9363.8, 10338.3, 11414.3, 12602.2, 13913.8, 15361.9, 16960.8, 18726, 20675, 22826.9, 25202.7, 27825.9, 30722.1, 33919.8, 37450.2, 41348.2, 45651.9, 50403.7, 55649.9, 61442.2, 67837.6, 74898.5, 82694.4, 91301.9, 100805.2, 111297.7, 122882.5, 135672.9, 149794.8, 165386.8, 182601.5, 201608.1, 222593.3, 245762.6, 271343.7, 299587.4, 330771.1, 365200.7, 403213.9, 445184, 491522.9, 542684.9, 599172.5, 661539.7, 730398.8, 806425.4, 890365.5, 983043, 9572683.4};
double[] normalTime = new double[] {1.00958241758242, 1.11495970695971, 1.06963166953528, 1.18127672595142, 1.15018594104308, 1.27023901906442, 1.2472594878124, 1.37744482155713, 1.41685187507839, 1.56473877113034, 1.56755170743479, 1.73116821561822, 1.74434730120433, 1.92641722153205, 1.95725417087426, 2.16154669376012, 2.21124718747179, 2.44205076596211, 2.50994901343847, 2.77193022359534, 2.86812333250013, 3.1674897409429, 3.29805772944222, 3.64229944530993, 3.80841107155634, 4.20592199148309, 4.42242809498221, 4.8840283338524, 5.15065412806684, 5.68826449160243, 6.02144053611861, 6.64994106345759, 7.05825151342297, 7.79497136835937, 8.29491528158907, 9.16071451973473, 9.77092350100014, 10.7907842031247, 11.311355104669, 12.4920015970756, 13.4631737052244, 14.8684207923017, 15.322810010546, 16.9221605503673, 17.602791084445, 19.4401194467945, 19.9138619998677, 21.9924132523791, 16.9295074753534, 18.6965604441613, 19.4662745138955, 21.4981078806657, 22.4508340041317, 24.794187048334, 21.9299806848883, 24.2189685678228, 25.3352524716474, 27.9796727633009, 24.6417064586782, 27.2137364257457, 27.7930719891776, 30.6940323651524, 30.0742869561431, 33.2133539448314, 33.3534941382039, 36.8348352772083, 37.0696258402337, 40.93884604578, 42.4260461563957, 46.8543540043697, 47.1239377238921, 52.0425978903589, 53.693321666918, 59.2976751068993, 60.1692757457264, 66.4495705205329, 66.7720718040988, 73.7415473122707, 76.8324023748064, 84.8519460570252, 88.1453522545292, 97.3457088871568, 101.175803906389, 111.736241351164, 116.429000968713, 128.581522955346, 133.995020100622, 147.981032299676, 154.311116147988, 170.417663624714, 178.555672255407, 197.192796295533, 207.556928886271, 229.221120116824, 239.701753082987, 264.721127983905, 278.790936846473, 307.890327561088, 325.297010290488, 359.250570287139, 376.451809570906, 415.744759391439, 439.247661643271, 485.09506067001, 506.047490207454, 558.867261912609, 590.119126007236, 651.714051617419, 691.908460702742, 764.127862324914, 796.957117808243, 880.14119407779, 939.928811085602, 1038.03585870733, 1082.69792300564, 1195.70679712407, 1262.42094024116, 1394.18878248856, 1488.70556306347, 14496.7280485445};

double[] secondCost = new double[] {205.809139511126, 205.666898683103, 205.510947895753, 205.361245312921, 205.196866006281, 205.037961182368, 204.861115491238, 204.68980138365, 204.499200257327, 204.304466121548, 204.089732263715, 203.875511955396, 203.639490465256, 203.403440451273, 203.141545545247, 202.877319302118, 202.586276067149, 202.289821292416, 201.962849114402, 201.628401442031, 201.259634189599, 200.884128316807, 200.470823998073, 200.047463215808, 199.579870710024, 199.098934496811, 198.568726422112, 198.019767421347, 197.414106074069, 196.785167022266, 196.091067618249, 195.36729726347, 194.568607981024, 193.733220320596, 192.811209255825, 191.843868432443, 190.776540948612, 189.653863969407, 188.414520387594, 187.116029983754, 185.682824831642, 184.156548244533, 182.471970368444, 180.744867551454, 178.837898847873, 176.892146461388, 174.744031015699, 172.563340671575, 170.155927101612, 168.448060074772, 166.562512333528, 164.653461422647, 162.545764924027, 160.406844613766, 158.045313603054, 156.136045952524, 153.988235498788, 151.784760223372, 149.351920748064, 147.503584655442, 145.462951839076, 143.506325452791, 141.346126978658, 139.472520504396, 137.403974289463, 135.544562182586, 133.491648277631, 131.713718729864, 129.75076664292, 127.774684202822, 125.573085489923, 123.762314431261, 121.763104645016, 120.117322794866, 118.300249603707, 116.783640524603, 114.939775999494, 113.850096472748, 112.647000728262, 110.627734605662, 107.826828419619, 105.60890512289, 103.160142677246, 101.141235060418, 98.3943606030692, 96.4191212414268, 94.1197186833565, 91.9810632039793, 89.6198071860878, 88.0967551101201, 85.6040436484927, 84.3265101874514, 82.221926362036, 80.9960672634902, 79.5357439871363, 78.2995243514211, 76.9346308757958, 75.9839103477244, 74.468989411611, 73.7032366599374, 71.4184976232158, 71.2078468065862, 68.9970151203599, 69.3621460275368, 65.7648099340712, 65.7648099340712, 63.4054359144346, 63.4054359144346, 61.4267301448194, 61.4267301448194, 58.4295546509364, 58.4295546509364, 56.8818318948696, 56.8818318948696, 54.0605778240308, 54.0605778240308, 51.9881981076397, 51.9881981076397, 50.5389169106641, 50.5389169106641};
double[] secondCost2 = new double[] {203.13233860099, 202.988993482163, 202.83183196634, 202.680772303242, 202.514902869252, 202.354348261486, 202.175666520585, 202.002343402015, 201.809507084666, 201.612311577817, 201.394863559453, 201.177636387015, 200.938302024462, 200.698606520352, 200.432666982947, 200.163983662474, 199.868030990072, 199.566147894276, 199.233188597443, 198.892128484954, 198.51607025227, 198.132501726134, 197.710323166839, 197.277156814418, 196.798734275924, 196.30585043449, 195.762470698387, 195.198956346536, 194.577236216113, 193.930575292604, 193.216917967109, 192.471554070454, 191.649036055106, 190.787344985998, 189.836303047305, 188.836911181175, 187.734219782183, 186.572493483566, 185.290042646251, 183.943974604858, 182.458255768343, 180.873997261643, 179.125423737726, 177.327672918664, 175.342698709217, 173.310851554106, 171.067687270979, 168.782062691008, 166.25880502424, 164.423053139412, 162.396315831693, 160.331400260874, 158.051620662669, 155.722735724616, 153.151469289297, 151.01064649224, 148.624436411962, 146.173777319575, 143.468024163638, 141.318387638638, 138.945107771579, 136.62122487126, 134.055559637202, 131.734290824981, 129.171505159301, 126.76642883342, 124.111065552939, 121.667993393022, 118.970679767243, 116.273634388718, 113.283811160463, 110.60278967096, 107.642766440354, 104.936178332934, 101.947891222429, 99.2288303248363, 96.1192999109482, 93.6322283836829, 90.8862970366724, 89.6688583891789, 87.9450600565222, 86.5393226499183, 84.9872775567425, 83.6651681411018, 81.8487685186973, 80.5094726227178, 78.954690408184, 77.4707819037332, 75.832421765823, 74.7640388864952, 73.0098766187729, 72.104918422045, 70.6542197712317, 69.8567106080253, 68.9065542546254, 68.1010156606756, 67.2116313316438, 66.574684853225, 65.5597456288688, 64.9942472119106, 63.3069972404224, 63.1531374790764, 61.538341766146, 61.8270638283787, 58.9825215696044, 58.9825215696044, 57.1539933435418, 57.1539933435418, 55.6254649227186, 55.6254649227186, 53.1343762606953, 53.1343762606953, 51.9271669220486, 51.9271669220486, 49.5277421737892, 49.5277421737892, 47.7862534445361, 47.7862534445361, 46.596228808774, 46.596228808774};
double[] reachLevel = new double[] {80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 83, 83, 83, 84, 84, 84, 85, 85, 86, 86, 87, 87, 88, 88, 89, 90, 90, 91, 91, 92, 93, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120};
double[] secondTime = new double[] {24.9946429257347, 24.9783842111745, 24.9604239225849, 24.9432943332101, 24.9243723855536, 24.9060506888359, 24.8858238572065, 24.8660689282208, 24.8442605111923, 24.8219115774579, 24.797227808174, 24.7726476204672, 24.7454977940721, 24.718299297897, 24.6882714810255, 24.6579417322399, 24.624439643112, 24.5903759437907, 24.5527527673272, 24.5143193989011, 24.4718684795311, 24.4282110190991, 24.3799813137437, 24.3300542238567, 24.2749163955096, 24.2175845383904, 24.1542567117313, 24.0880317336631, 24.0148862553222, 23.9381519219767, 23.8534012345939, 23.7641440208121, 23.6655607949053, 23.5614444982819, 23.4464515869104, 23.3246787903348, 23.1901789836552, 23.0474035039304, 22.8897163219235, 22.7256509515522, 22.544445507274, 22.3498647994608, 22.1349546550305, 21.9158909898917, 21.6739535964416, 21.4248306343984, 21.1496883589048, 20.8717319487254, 20.5647412156741, 20.3483217811742, 20.1092907297184, 19.8649748206746, 19.595132087265, 19.3186025584435, 19.0131802946162, 18.7667111995194, 18.490451007457, 18.2047319219977, 17.8891513821645, 17.6448833971303, 17.3750629489418, 17.1147038849072, 16.8271013961493, 16.5731352612704, 16.2923706355883, 16.0378836320328, 15.7567402789638, 15.5063131557712, 15.2296329829085, 14.9463360163191, 14.6310161166959, 14.3596539672288, 14.0595718337876, 13.7912768736783, 13.4947912766823, 13.2295985529344, 12.9181982399467, 12.684004188419, 12.425408200958, 12.212164466137, 11.9147945189033, 11.678465792127, 11.4174452967627, 11.202029099851, 10.9072154065515, 10.6977333721524, 10.4482346235909, 10.2179425784472, 9.96261811883693, 9.79890600858667, 9.5292281368228, 9.39100021700554, 9.13546626658899, 8.95336286950375, 8.73661022043875, 8.5538243186338, 8.35021455477117, 8.21361702837751, 7.99254171400577, 7.89238136322017, 7.58748131883126, 7.5609402291254, 7.26239303170813, 7.30945047798586, 6.86457666518511, 6.86457666518511, 6.56680908628267, 6.56680908628267, 6.31619233951591, 6.31619233951591, 5.96806504391798, 5.96806504391798, 5.77411467139106, 5.77411467139106, 5.456191060476, 5.456191060476, 5.21889040213051, 5.21889040213051, 5.04794996442499, 5.04794996442499};

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

JPanel x = new JPanel() {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Image oi = getImage(getCodeBase(), "Logo.png");

        g.drawImage(oi, 0, 200, 537, 93, null);

    }
};

public void init() {

    t.setBounds(25, 25, 220, 25);
    t.setSelected(true);
    t.addActionListener(this);
    t.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    z.setBounds(250, 25, 150, 25);
    z.addActionListener(this);
    z.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    group.add(t);
    group.add(z);

    leech.setBounds(30, 100, 160, 25);
    leech.setOpaque(true);
    leech.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    t2.setBounds(30, 125, 50, 25);
    t2.setSelected(true);
    t2.addActionListener(this);
    t2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    z2.setBounds(85, 125, 50, 25);
    z2.addActionListener(this);
    z2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    ButtonGroup group2 = new ButtonGroup();
    group2.add(t2);
    group2.add(z2);

    p.setBounds(30, 50, 160, 25);
    p.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    p.setOpaque(true);

    e.setBounds(195, 50, 150, 25);
    e.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    e.setOpaque(true);

    startLevel.setBounds(30, 75, 150, 25);
    startLevel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    startLevel.setText("1");

    endLevel.setBounds(195, 75, 150, 25);
    endLevel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    endLevel.setText("1");

    cost.setBounds(225, 100, 150, 25);
    cost.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    cost.setOpaque(true);

    chaotics.setBounds(225, 120, 160, 25);
    chaotics.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    chaotics.setOpaque(true);

    time.setBounds(225, 140, 150, 25);
    time.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    time.setOpaque(true);

    calc.setBounds(155, 175, 90, 25);
    calc.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    calc.addActionListener(this);

    x.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 293);
    x.setVisible(true);
    x.setLayout(null);
    x.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    x.add(t);
    x.add(z);
    x.add(startLevel);
    x.add(endLevel);
    x.add(p);
    x.add(e);
    x.add(cost);
    x.add(chaotics);
    x.add(time);
    x.add(calc);
    x.add(t2);
    x.add(z2);
    x.add(leech);

    this.add(x);

    endLevel.setVisible(false);
    e.setVisible(false);

    calc.doClick();

    this.setSize(400, 293);
    this.setVisible(true);

}

public static double round(double value, int places) {
    if (places < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    long factor = (long) Math.pow(10, places);
    value = value * factor;
    long tmp = Math.round(value);
    return (double) tmp / factor;
}


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

    if(t.isSelected()) {

        endLevel.setVisible(false);
        e.setVisible(false);

        if(startLevel.getText().length() < 1) {

        } else {

            double cost1 = 0;
            double chaotic = 0;
            double time = 0;


            for(int i = 0; i <= normalCost.length; i++) {
                if(Integer.parseInt(startLevel.getText()) == i) {
                    if(z2.isSelected()){
                        cost1 = secondCost2[i - 1];
                    } else {
                        cost1 = secondCost[i - 1];
                    }
                    time = secondTime[i - 1];
                    chaotic = reachLevel[i - 1];
                }
            }

            cost.setText("It will cost: " + round(cost1, 2) + "m");
            chaotics.setText("You will reach level: " + round(chaotic, 2));
            this.time.setText("It will take: " + round(time, 2) + " hours");

        }

        x.repaint();

    } else if(z.isSelected()) {

        endLevel.setVisible(true);
        e.setVisible(true);

        if((startLevel.getText().length() < 1) || (endLevel.getText().length() < 1)) {

        } else {

            double cost1 = 0;
            double chaotic = 0;
            double time = 0;

            for(int i = 0; i <= normalCost.length; i++) {
                if(!((Integer.parseInt(startLevel.getText())) >= (i))) {
                    if(!(Integer.parseInt(endLevel.getText()) < (i))) {
                        if(z2.isSelected()){
                            cost1 = cost1 + normalCost2[i - 2];
                        } else {
                            cost1 = cost1 + normalCost[i - 2];
                        }
                        chaotic = chaotic + normalTokens[i - 2];
                        time = time + normalTime[i - 2];
                    }
                }
            }

            cost.setText("It will cost: " + round(cost1, 2) + "m");
            chaotics.setText("You will gain: " + round(chaotic / 200000, 2) + " chaotics");
            this.time.setText("It will take: " + round(time / 60, 2) + " hours");

        }

        x.repaint();
    }

}

}
```

To clarify some, this works as intended for other people. As far as I know, he's the only one having problems.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please restrict your code sample to a relevant portion. The ideal sample is [short, self-contained and compilable](http://sscce.org/). Reading through an entire source code is time-consuming, and will net you less answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue here is that Mac vs Windows vs Linux display Swing components differently. If you want it to look the same on all OSes you will have to use a non-default L&F.

I can see already that the guy having trouble is on Mac OSX because of how the GUI looks.

Comment: What do you mean by a non-default L&F? Does setting the layout to null not accomplish that?

Comment: L&F = Look and Feel. It is a major aspect of how components are displayed in Java Swing. Read the Java tutorials to learn more, the topic is much larger than the scope of your question. Layout is a slightly different concept.

Comment: I got that part of it fixed; thanks very much.

Any idea about why my image wouldn't be displaying until after it gets refreshed once?

Comment: what image? You provided a huge amount of code. Please upvote/accept my answer and repost with only the relevant portions of the code.